# How to return latlong of Adress from Edittext using Google maps Api (Geocoding) in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

This question is for Google Maps Geocoding Api and not Geocode function in Android. I am new to Android coding

I am using the Transport tracker Demo Android app link - https://github.com/googlemaps/transport-tracker

I want to fetch the latlong of a specific address when the user enters any address into the **EDITTEXT** and then send it to the database.

It it possible to fetch the latlong from the Google Maps api (Geocoding) as per the address https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters. I don't want to use the Geocoder inbuilt function in Android Studio.

Comment: use autocomplete https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

Comment: On a side note, fetching that latlngs and saving it to database might be in violation of Google Maps Platform Terms of Service particularly in item 3.2.3 (b) No caching: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license.

Comment: @jabamataro if such is the case then where uber is storing the locations of the drivers ?